# Custom ruleset for phpcs using PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I'm trying to somehow convince the phpcs to use the Zend coding guidelines, -but- to allow me to have variables with underscores (like `$blub->foo_bar`).

Could anyone tell me how to change the ruleset that phpcs uses from within PHPStorm, please?

Answer (score 17):

You'll need to create a custom coding standard if you want to override the built-in ones. This is just a matter of creating an XML file with the standard's definition in it.

In your case, you want the whole Zend coding standard, but you don't want the particular naming convention rule about variable names. So you would create a file called `mystandard.xml` (name it whatever you want and put it where ever you want) and put in the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyStandard">
 <description>My custom Zend coding standard.</description>
 <rule ref="Zend">
  <exclude name="Zend.NamingConventions.ValidVariableName"/>
 </rule>
</ruleset>
```

There is a lot more you can do to customise your standard, including bringing in checks from other standards, overwriting messages or muting some of them. You can take a look at the docs here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.annotated-ruleset.php

Last I checked, PHPStorm didn't let you use custom coding standards, for whatever reason. Normally, you'd just type in the name of the standard as the full path to the `mystandard.xml` file. If PHPStorm still doesn't let you do that, the only way to trick it is to actually install your custom standard.

Note that this is not something you normally need to do and it is a bit complicated. But if you want to try it, this is how you do it:

1. Find where PHPCS is installed on your system. If you don't know where that is, try `pear config-show | grep php_dir`. PHP_CodeSniffer will be in a directory under there. For me, PEAR is installed in `/usr/local/PEAR`, so PHP_CodeSniffer is found at `/usr/local/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer`
2. Create a new directory called `MyStandard` under `/usr/local/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards`
3. Put your `mystandard.xml` file directly in there but rename it to `ruleset.xml`

To confirm your standard has been installed, run `phpcs -i`. You should see

```
The installed coding standards are MySource, MyStandard, PEAR, PHPCS, Squiz and Zend
```

Now, PHPStorm will show (hopefully) `MyStandard` as an option in the drop-down. If it doesn't show up, then they've probably hard-coded the list and there wont be any way to make it work without hacking up the Zend coding standard directly.

I hope that information helps find you a solution. If not, you can always run PHPCS directly on the command line using your custom standard:

```
phpcs --standard=/path/to/mystandard.xml /path/to/code
```

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to add your own custom ruleset on phpstorm, this can be done in the project settings => inspections => "PHP Code Sniffer validation", using the coding standard "Custom" and set the root directory of your custom ruleset.xml

Answer (score 1):

The list of standards is not hardcoded, it's obtained from phpcs. Installing your own standard as described above will do the job.

Comment: I spent the better part of the afternoon trying to get this to work. PHPStorm won't even load the list of installed standards, the only options in the inspector settings are blank and custom, and even selecting custom the validate option never shows. I can get phpcs to run CLI properly but it would be nice to have it work as prescribed in the docs for PHPStorm.